# Android Media Player Release won't stop playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Here's my scenario:

I have a timer that counts down from 20 seconds.  At 13 seconds, a sound starts playing.  At 0 seconds, I stop the current sound, load up a new sound and play that new sound.  Once that sounds finishes, I load up the previous sound, set it to loop, and start it.

This is the logic for hitting 0 seconds:

```
mp.stop();
mp = MediaPlayer.create(mActivity, R.raw.second_sound);
mp.start();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(mActivity, R.raw.first_sound);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Once the last sound starts playing, calling mp.release() doesn't stop the player.  Any ideas as to how to stop the player?

Note: mp.release() works during the first time I start playing and during the second sound but not during the looping sound.

**Solution: My global MediaPlayer is also named "mp". Oops.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `mp` `MediaPlayer` objects mixed up a little. If `mp.release()` is being called outside of the `onCompletion()` method, it is not referring to the looping instance created there. Change the identifiers in `onCompletion()` to refer to the "outer" `mp`. For example, if your code is in `MainActivity`:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            MainActivity.this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chirp);
            MainActivity.this.mp.setLooping(true);
            MainActivity.this.mp.start();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating new media player every time and not releasing old one onCompltion? did you try setDataSource?